# Bi directional data binding and type safety in angular2

Tags: angular

I have a little doubt regarding bi directional data binding and type safety. This is my code:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="user.age">
   <ion-option value="25">Noob</ion-option>
   <ion-option value="37">Dynamic</ion-option>
   <ion-option value="67">Samurai</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Now the problem is that if a user in the front end (ignore the ionic part) chooses an option, a string is passed to the model goal. In the Model of course I defined :number as type. How can I (without huge efforts, aka model driven forms) pass in a number into ngModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the property binding on value to receive back a number.

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="user.age" (ionChange)="change()">
  <ion-option [value]="25">Noob</ion-option>
  <ion-option [value]="37">Dynamic</ion-option>
  <ion-option [value]="67">Samurai</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: Oh you can remove that. It's the callback that is called when an item is changed. I was using it to test for type of "user.age"

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks and see you in gitter.